# Linux disk full

Tags: linux, usb-storage, backtrack

I'm trying to copy a 2GB file from a USB flash drive to a BackTrack 5 image mounted on VMware Player but it keeps saying disk is full in the middle of the transferring process even when there's plenty of space free. What can I do?

Comment: Is the VM's file system in read only mode somehow?

Comment: Hmm how can I check if it is? I mean, I can create files and edit them inside the virtual image, do you mean windows vm folder? I'm new to all this.

Comment: How do you know there is lots of free space left on the disk? Can you post the output of *df -h* ?

Comment: Looking at this answer on Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/a/349025/76672 will let your list mount point that are read only.